# OutOfMemoryException with very simple WPF application with Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, binding, frameworks, entity, out-of-memory

I have searched for this question, but I have only found questions where people were loading tables with millions of entries. This is not the case in my situation.

I am fairly new to WPF and new to Entity Framework. I used the Visual Studio 2010 Data Source Wizard to add a connection to a database. I used drag and drop to drag a view from the data source into my WPF window. The view only contains about 32,000 records and takes about 15 seconds to select.

When I built and ran the application the first time, it worked fine and displayed the data in the window. Just to get a feel for the difference, I display the same data in both a ListView and a Datagrid, but it is no different when I use only one of the controls:

When I run the application the second time, it never finishes starting up. It only displays the 'busy' cursor and then throws an OutOfMemoryException after a while. If I watch the performance in Task manager, the memory just keeps rising and rising until it hits the exception.

I have debugged this: It does not happen when executing the EF query. I have even made it save the query results to a list and assign that to the datasource of the window. I can see in the debugger that the query terminates and the list is generated fine, I can inspect it in the debugger.

It's the data binding mechanism *after* the query is run that seems to leak memory like nothing and then throw. By the way, there is no call stack that I could post.

Has anyone else had this problem, and how did you solve it?

Here is some more information: It's Windows 7.

MainWindow.xaml looks like this:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="vMyViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:VMyView, CreateList=True}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vMyViewSource}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="my view in a ListView:"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  Margin="0" 
                  Name="vMyListView" 
                  SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Control.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="IDColumn1" Header="ID" Width="80">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Margin="6,-1,-6,-1" Text="{Binding Path=ID,Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Name" Header="Name" Width="80">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    ... (more GridViewColumns)
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="my view in a DataGrid:"/>

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  Margin="0" 
                  Name="vMyViewDataGrid" 
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IDColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                ... (more DataGridTextColumns, also some with a CellTemplate with a TextBox inside)
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is the Window_Loaded method of MainWindow (most of this code was autogenerated by the Data Source Wizard):

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WpfApplication2.MyEntities MyEntities = new WpfApplication2.MyEntities();
        // Load data into VMyView. You can modify this code as needed.
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource VMyViewViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("vMyViewViewSource")));
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<WpfApplication2.VMyView> VMyViewQuery = this.GetVMyViewQuery(MyEntities);
        var data = VMyViewQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly).ToList(); // I added the ToList() to make the query execute here
        VMyViewViewSource.Source = data;
    } // it gets here fine and loads the data
```

I can't believe there is anything out of the ordinary here, what is going on and how can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: did you use a DataGridTemplateColumn? this bad thing had a memoryleak built in :) http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/400881

Comment: I sometimes see that when I create a Template of some kind and mistakenly bind to the control's UI content instead of its data content. For example, a template with a `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }" />` will simply insert a copy of the template in the UI, which creates a new ContentPresenter with it's content set to `{Binding }`, which repeats the cycle endlessly until it runs out of member. This is because `{Binding }` evaluates to the `ContentPresenter`, not the Content. To fix it, you have to use `{Binding Content}` so you're binding to the data content and not the UI content.